# Fedora boot errors after a update

Tags: fedora, mount, boot, superblock

I did an update on my Fedora USB stick and after that there were errors booting and I got into ermergency mode.

Error:
[image]

Comment: Your storage might by dying, please check it using `badblocks` (it may kill it entirely, so do have backups).

Comment: What do you mean with badblocks?